# Play framework, configuration parameter injection in my custom class.

Tags: scala, playframework

Is there another way than using a subclass of the Controller to benefit from the injected Play Framework pooled database parameter db ?

This is what the [Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase) recommends :

```
class ScalaControllerInject @Inject()(db: Database) extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    var outString = "Number is "
    val conn = db.getConnection()

    ...

    Ok(outString)
  }

}
```

However I would like to have another class querying the database. This is because I am not using a subclass of the Controller class : I am using a websocket Actor.

This something I would like to aim for:

```
object MyWebSocketActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new MyWebSocketActor(out))
}

class MyWebSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  val gson = ToolSingleton.getInstance().getGsonTool()

  def receive = {
    case msg: String => {
        val dbm=(new DbManager(...  )). query(msg)
      }

    }

}

class DbManager @Inject()(db: Database) extends /* ? */ {

  def query(s : String) {
    var outString = "Number is "
    val conn = db.getConnection()

    ...

  }

}
```

How should I extend DbManager in order to use the function query from my actor MyWebSocketActor?

Comment: Your DbManager doesn't need to extend anything. Simply inject it in the actor and then -- assuming you're using the actor from the controller -- inject the actor in the controller. There's AkkaGuiceSupport to help you with that: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka

Comment: I am sorry, I am a beginner with Scala and the Play Framework. How do I verify that the actor I am using is from the controller?

Comment: Declare the dependencies as parameters of the constructor, possibly using DI to inject it from a context.

Comment: Nono I didn't mean 'from the controller'. I mean, where are you using the actor? One way could be ```class MyController @Inject() (@Named("my-actor") actorRef: ActorRef) {``` the docs I linked above show how to define the binding of the actor (ie. which concrete actor will be used for this `ActorRef`)

Comment: Don't be shy guys and try to answer rather than comment :D

Comment: Thanks, but I would want to be able to get the reference to the Play framework database connectiong object. It is not the actor I would like to bind, it is the Database db reference.

Comment: I found a lateral way to connect to the database in a "clean" way. Unfortunately, it does not use the default database configured in the framework. I had to redefine it again. This is the reference page for the method I used: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithDatabases . 
It is not perfect but it is quite simple: it makes use of the withDatabase  helper function. Ideally, I would like to reuse the definition from the configuration file to avoid repeating myself. Any other suggestions are appreciated :)